# Excel Cut And Paste Specific Characters

Tags: xlsm

I wish to create a macro that will cut characters 49 thru 56 from each cell in a column and paste those characters in the column directly to the right.  There are 4000 rows of data that need to be manipulated.

Examples of data:

```
Stop: Coggins Drive and Jones Rd NW 04 Feb 2013 07:40:00:000
Stop: Coggins Drive and Jones Rd NW 04 Feb 2013 08:20:00:000
Stop: Coggins Drive and Jones Rd NW 04 Feb 2013 08:40:00:000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a function would be simpler.

Assume that the example data is in column A, starting at row A3. in cell B3, enter the formula below and FIll Down to the end of the data.

```
=MID(A3,49,7)
```

Once the function has pulled out the substring, select the range of cells in column B and copy then paste special, values only. THis replaces the functions with the actual values.

If you need this as a macro then use the macro recorder to record the above actions. :-)

Note: You might want to tag the question 'Excel" and "macro".

Comment: It almost worked. It copied instead of cut. As you can see, these numbers represent time. I need them removed from the original data.